# How can i authenatciation in app purchase item in android

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

i am using in-App purchase in my Android application . After that any user purchase app i want to verify it's receipt like ios it is possible in android ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, using `getPurchases` from the Iabhelper library provided by Google.
You can verify the receipt by checking a user's inventory and the ITEM_SKU value.

You can find out:

- all the items the user has purchased
- if the purchase has already been consumed

Here's more documentation on all the methods: https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/api

Comment: Thanks for replay but i want to like that.
https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/releasenotes/General/ValidateAppStoreReceipt/Chapters/ValidateRemotely.html

is it possible in android ?

Comment: @MehulTank, what are you running that is giving you the error?